# xen + libvirt share disks betwee VM on diferent hosts

Tags: xen, sles, libvirt

I have another problem.

what I've done is:

1. We deploy 2 physical hosts with `SLES 12 SP1` and install `XEN hypervizor` on both.
2. On each host we provide few block devices via `FC`.
3. On each host we deploy `fullvirt` Virtual Machine with `SLES 12 SP1` guest system.
4. Block devices connected to each of VM as `scsi` or `xendisk` (`virsh dumpxml` above)
5. from one of VM, we create `LVM` on disks (1 VG per 1 PV) `fs=ext3`
6. after rescan another VM can see new VG

example:

1. on VM1:

   ```
   mount /dev/vg1/lv1 /srv/lv1
   echo 'test from 1st vm' > /srv/lv1/1test.txt
   umount /srv/lv1
   vgchange -an vg1 && vgexport vg1
   ```
2. on VM2:

   ```
   vgimport vg1 && vgchange -ay vg1
   mount /dev/vg1/lv1 /srv/lv1
   cat /srv/lv1/1test.txt
   test from 1st vm

   echo 'answer from 2nd vm' >> /srv/lv1/1test.txt
   echo 'test from 2nd vm' > /srv/lv1/2test.txt
   umount /srv/lv1
   vgchange -an vg1 && vgexport vg1
   ```
3. on VM1:

   ```
   mount /dev/vg1/lv1 /srv/lv1
   cat /srv/lv1/1test.txt
   test from 1st vm
   cat /srv/lv1/2test.txt
   no such file
   ```

What I need as result:

Devices must be consistent, and have same files.

Additional info:

- no lock configured;
- if I do same steps on physical hosts, all works good;
- shared disk config:

  ```
  disk type='block' device='disk'
  driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
  source dev='/dev/mapper/360002ac0000000000000003200019bcc'/>
  target dev='sdd' bus='scsi'/>
  address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='1'/>
  /disk>
  ```

also tried with different disk options, such as:

```
driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none' io='native'/>
```

Any idea, how to resolve this issue?